# Java thread hanging when trying to interrupt and join main

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, freeze, runnable

So I've been struggling with this problem for a whole day now, and having consulted some threading tutorials and examples am still failing to achieve my desired result.

I have a Thread whose only job is to poll a LinkedBlockingQueue of Strings and then use a PrintWriter to deliver the Strings over a socket to a client. That functionality is working fine, but I am now trying to enhance it by allowing it to gracefully fail in the event of a connection interruption and restart. In order to accomplish this, I am calling interrupt on the thread, and then join, with the end goal of recreating the Thread object to start over. Unfortunately the Thread hangs on the call of join which must mean the Thread never actually manages to die, but I am totally bewildered as to why this might be. Relevant code below.

```
try {
    resultSetStreamer.interrupt();
    resultSetStreamer.join();
    logger.info("Streamer finished.");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Actual thread code;

```
class ResultSetStreamer implements Runnable {

    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            logger.debug("Thread started.");

            // Blocks and waits for an external connection.
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Creates a compression stream using best possible compression
            // to the external connection.
            gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()) {
                {
                    def.setLevel(compression);
                }
            };
            PrintWriter toClient = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(gzos), bufferSize), false);

            while (true) {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }
                if (moreRowsToReceive || !dataBuffer.isEmpty()) {
                    // Synchronisation point.
                    String row = dataBuffer.poll(pollTime,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    if (row != null) {
                        toClient.println(row);
                        logger.trace("Current row: " + ++currentCount + ".");
                    }
                } else {
                    toClient.flush();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                gzos.finish();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        logger.debug("Thread finished.");
    }
}
```

Main place to look at is the while(true) loop, which should always loop around and check if the Thread has been interrupted, in which case it throws the exception which is caught at the bottom in order to allow the Thread to die. I don't think the PrintWriter should be blocking the execution of code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be just catching `InterruptedException` and print the stack trace.  The acceptable ways of dealing with an `InterruptedException` are discussed [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will read into that. It's worth mentioning that I am not currently utilising the Executor interfaces. My current code is using the basic Thread/Runnable class/interface.

Comment: That article isn't specific to executors ;)

Comment: Check that you are even in the while loop. That behavior would occur if you are blocking on the ServerSocket's accept().

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure. Quickly skimmed the article and realised my initial question could be ambiguous to that, as Executors also use Runnable.

Comment: @ChrisMoran Definitely in the while loop, client side is showing strings transferred. Does the flush method of PrintWriter ever block?

Comment: I don't understand - if you are a server, just exit the thread if the socket closes - the client should open any new connection, so starting a new client-server thread.  Why are you aparrently trying to manage the connection from outside the server-client thread?

Comment: Not that it's a big deal but _Thread.interrupted()_ returns and clears the interrupt flag for the current thread.

Comment: Instead of throwing an exception. Try break-ing out of the loop.

Comment: Is pollTime set to 0 or infinite? Is it possible that poll(...) is blocking forever?

Comment: @MartinJames Maybe I wasn't clear. The purpose of the code is for the client to attempt to reconnect to the server should its stream be disrupted. It has an alternative method of communicating with the server outside of the socket stream which is working perfectly (Hessian, if anyone is curious). The server is what accepts a client's connection, but is unaware if the client closes that connection from its end, so I need to interrupt the thread in order to re-initialise it and allow the client to reconnect to its socket.

Comment: @ChrisMoran The exception is never thrown in the first place, the code in that if statement is never reached. pollTime is set to 10ms, so should not be blocking.

Comment: @DavidH - why does it matter what socket the client connects up to?  If the client 'silently' shuts down, (someone trips over power cable), it will later reconnect using a different socket-pair.  When that happens, and the client logs on, you should then reconcile any outstanding issues with other threads that are still waiting on a a stale, half-open socket connection that will never receive anything.  This is much easier to do if there is some timeout/keepalive exchange with the client - any thread that does not receive any request or keep-alive for some interval can just die on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM does not enforce interruption to terminate the thread. You need to make sure that all blocking calls that your code invokes support interruption.

For example, if client is not receiving data, output buffer will fill up and  toClient.println() will block, but this call does not support interruptions so calling .interrupt() won't terminate it.

I would advice to add more debug logs to determine where exactly the code blocks.

Comment: It would seem from the JConsole stack trace that you are correct about toClient.println() blocking. Do you have a suggestion to closing this socket on interruption? Would it be appropriate to extend Thread, and override interupt() to include closing the socket?

Comment: Technically it should work. According to the Socket documentation, close() causes all threads blocked on the socket to throw SocketException. I wonder if it is the cleanest solution, because your class would need to extend complex Thread class. Maybe it would be better to keep a reference to Thread that executes ResultSetStreamer in ResultSetStreamer and have a method like: void terminate() { socket.close(); thread.interrupt() }?

Comment: Thanks for this, I got the thread to die. In the end I anonymously extended the class in this way:

`resultSetStreamer = new Thread(new ResultSetStreamer(), "streamer") {
 @Override
 public void interrupt() {
  super.interrupt();
  try {
   clientSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
};
resultSetStreamer.start();`

Which sends the interrupt signal then closes the blocking socket.

Answer (score 1):

On the machine you're running, try starting up jconsole and attaching to your running program.  Under the "threads" tab, you should be able to click on each thread and see what it's currently doing.  This should give you an indication of what statement on your Runnable object has not yet completed.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I was unaware of the tool JConsole. Tried running it, seems like the Thread is blocked on writing to the socket. What is the best way to close the socket from outside the Thread so it throws an exception and exits? Top line from JConsole Stacktrace below;

`java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)`